# Materialize JS not working?

Tags: javascript, materialize

I believe I have initialized my code incorrectly, but I can't get Materialize JS (Carousel) to work. I just asked a question earlier this week on Materialize CSS formatting, and I assumed that the JS was fixed as well. Where have I gone wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <!-- CAROUSEL -->
  <h1>CAROUSEL</h1>
  <div class="carousel">
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="sample-1.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="sample-1.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="sample-1.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="sample-1.jpg"></a>
      <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="sample-1.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- PUSHING THE END OF THE SCREEN -->
<div style="height:500px"></div>

<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- INTIALIZATION -->
<script>
var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var instance = M.Carousel.init(elem, options);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to init the carousel two times.

First with vanilla JS

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var instance = M.Carousel.init(elem, options);
```

Then with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

And the second line in the vanilla JS causes an error.